# Find a multiplicative inverse of an element in a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, inverse

Suppose we have an element $\sigma=p+qa\rho+rd\rho^{-1}\in K$ where $K=\mathbb{Q}(\rho)$ where $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=3$

I want to find a multiplicative inverse of $\sigma$ i .e

$\sigma^{-1}=s+ta\rho+ud\rho^{-1}\in K$ such that

$\sigma\sigma^{-1}=1$

my first idea was to simply multiply these two elements and make it equal to $1$

$(p+qa\rho+rd\rho^{-1})(s+ta\rho+ud\rho^{-1})=1$

$\begin{equation}\begin{split}1&=\\
&=ps+pta\rho+pud\rho^{-1}+sqa\rho+qta^2\rho^2+quad+rsd\rho^{-1}+rtad+rud^2\rho^{-2}\end{split}\end{equation}$

but I have hard time with determining coeffiecients $s,ta,ud$. I get only 4 equations but many more variables.  Is there a better way? perhaps with some matrix equation?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You need to specify the minimal polynomial of $\rho$. Otherwise the question is too general. That there is a solution is simply because $K$ is a field ...

Comment: the minimal polynomial of $\rho$ is $ax^3-bx^2+cx-d\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: Use that polynomial to transform $\rho^{\pm 2}$ into something on the form $p+q\rho+r\rho^{-1}$. Otherwise your original idea is sound.